# Invoking DOORS Database using C# and update modules

Tags: c#, ibm-doors

I would like to invoke DOORS Database client version 9.5 using `C#` and import test cases in DOORS module which is in `.csv` format.

I know their is DOORS API Manual but that is for; `C` and DOORS Database client version 9.2, but i am working on DOORS Database 9.5.

Furthermore, the best way to do this is by using `DXL` scripts but i have to create an API and communicate between 2 databases so i need `DOORS API` and `MySQL database API` and communicate between them.

Is their any way, i can perform these tasks using `DOORS C# API` rather than invoking DOORS from `C#` and then run `DXL` script to perform the tasks?